# Scrollreveal.js doesn't apply the animations

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im getting started with scrollreveal.js. But when I'm linking my script with the html file the modifications that I made in the script doesn't apply. I'm always getting the default animation. I tried to put my script in the body and it didn't change anything.
Here is my Javascript and HTML code:

```js
ScrollReveal().reveal('.headline',{ origin: 'left' }, { duration: 2000 });
```

```html
<body>
      <h1 class="headline">HELLO WORLD</h1>
     
      
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal@4.0.0/dist/scrollreveal.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/scroller.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues with your snippet:

1. You are trying to pass 2 options objects to `reveal` but it only takes a single one. This means that your line:

```js
ScrollReveal().reveal('.headline', { origin: 'left' }, { duration: 2000 });
```

should actually be:

```js
ScrollReveal().reveal('.headline', { origin: 'left', duration: 2000 });
```

2. If you check out the [documentation](https://scrollrevealjs.org/api/origin.html) for the `origin` option, it states:

> You will need a non-zero value assigned to options.distance for options.origin to have any visible impact on your animations.

This means that if you want to use `origin`, you'll also need to specify a `distance` which will specify how much the element will move when revealed. This goes with `origin` because the element will move and be revealed from the direction specified with `origin`.

I've fixed your snippet and added a `distance` of `100px` so when the `h1` is revealed, it comes in `100px` from the left.

```js
ScrollReveal().reveal('.headline', { duration: 2000, origin: 'left', distance: '100px' });
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal@4.0.7/dist/scrollreveal.js"></script>

<h1 class="headline">Widget, Inc.</h1>
```

Comment: @Redhood glad to be of help, don't forget to accept this answer if it solved the problem for you so that it maybe help others in the future.